# Force download in Codeigniter then stay with the thanks page

Tags: codeigniter

I have a form , when i validate i want to redirect the user to the thank you page then force download the file 
what is happening here is redirect the user to the download page ( blank page ) then download start .. and when i remove the 'refresh' from redirect function it download the file instantaneously 
here is my code

**controller**

```
public function index()
{

    if ($this->form_validation->run('price') == FALSE) {
        // Validation problems 
        $this->load->view('control_front', array('page' => 'price'));
    }
    else
    {   

        redirect('price/thanks', 'refresh');
    }
}
public function download()
{

    $this->load->helper('download');
    $data = file_get_contents("./uploads/price-list-2013.pdf"); // Read the file's contents
    $name = 'pricelist.pdf';

    force_download($name, $data);
            // doesn't go the view page
    $this->load->view('control_front', array('page' => 'thanks'));

}
```

What i need to do here is to load the thank you page then the force download .. how can i do that ?

Comment: You will need to use javascript. If you are worried of people having javascript turned off (which is very few), you could add a link saying "If your download does not start automatically, please click here"

Answer (score 0):

I usually use this function in js file, inside setTimeout for delay X seconds.
You can put this code, with file route, in php view.

```
function downloadURL(url)
{
    var iframe;
    iframe = document.getElementById("hiddenDownloader");
    if (iframe === null)
    {
        iframe = document.createElement('iframe');  
        iframe.id = "hiddenDownloader";
        iframe.style.visibility = 'hidden';
        document.body.appendChild(iframe);
    }
    iframe.src = url;  
}
```

---

---

Comment: Perhaps give a small explanation of what your code snippet does? Might not be too obvious for people new to javascript

Comment: but i don't want to use javascript .. i want to get to thanks page then download the pdf file